# Bash vs. Zsh, git grep works in a bash for loop but not a zsh for loop?

Tags: bash, zsh

The following works in bash but does not in zsh and I'm unsure why:

```
user@machine:~/some_git_repo$ for i in $(ls ./conf); do git --no-pager grep $i ; done
```

The zsh shell results in the following for each file in `./conf`

```
fatal: command line, 'some_file_name.xml': Unmatched [ or [^
```

Comment: It's not safe to do in bash either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a command substitution here at all. Instead, use a glob -- and see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

```
# this works reliably in both bash and zsh
for i in ./conf/*; do git --no-pager grep -F -e "${i##*/}"; done
```

Note the use of `grep -F` -- this means that your argument is treated as a literal string, not a regexp, so you can't have filenames that are invalid regex syntax.

Comment: And `zsh` being `zsh`, you can simply write `$i:t` to get the file name.

Comment: @chepner, sure. I'm aiming for a portable answer here, by way of both staying inside my comfort zone knowledge-wise and avoiding encouraging zsh-specific habits when a portable option is available.

Comment: Why does  `for i in $(ls ./conf); do echo "$i 1" ; done` correctly output each of the file names in the `./conf` director with a ` 1` append if `$(...)` parses to a single string?

Comment: @rudolph9, first -- try creating filenames with spaces in there, or even better, running `touch 'conf/foo * bar'`, and observing output from your existing command. Second, give me a minute to review zsh's rules -- *in general* it doesn't string-split by default, but there may be an exception for command substitutions within `for` loops.

Comment: Parameter expansions don't undergo word-splitting, but command substitutions still do.

Comment: I'm not aware of any operating systems where `zsh` is the default, let alone *only*, POSIX-compatible shell. I would imagine most people using it are doing so *because* of its various non-standard shortcuts, especially for interactive use. In this case, you could just write `for i (./conf/*) git --no-pager grep -F -e $i:t`.

Comment: @chepner, it's not the behaviors added in undefined space that bug me (would be awfully hypocritical if they did), but non-compliant behaviors added in spaces that *are* defined. Anyhow, whether zsh is default anywhere is entirely moot -- my problem is getting folks in the habit of being able to use `$foo` unquoted safely, because habits carry. fish isn't such a problem because it's so different from POSIX that there's less risk of habits bleeding over, but zsh is close enough to carry that risk.